# java collec to list ignored

Tags: java, filter, lambda

I am trying to write lambda in java that filter list by month and add data in the current month to the new list but when I try to collect the data I get an error collect is ignored.

```
public String getMonthlyExpensesNew() {
        Functions functions = new Functions();
        List<ShoppingMgnt> monthlyData = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            monthlyData = getRecordsAsList();

            monthlyData.stream().filter(date -> functions.checkForCurrentMonth(date.getPurchaseDate())).collect(Collectors.toList());

        }catch (SQLException sqlException){
            System.err.println("Error in getMonthlyExpensesNew");
        }

        return String.valueOf(monthlyData);
    }


public boolean checkForCurrentMonth(String givenDate){
        LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate monthToCheck = LocalDate.parse(givenDate);
        return currentDate.getMonth().equals(monthToCheck.getMonth());
    }
```

Comment: Of course it's ignored, because you don't save the result of `collect` anywhere, so it is immediately discarded. Where do you expect the collected list to exist?

Comment: Probably a warning by your IDE? The code will run just fine. Problem is that you create a stream and collect the data of it back into a list, but you aren't saving the created list in a variable.

Comment: You don’t need a stream here.  `monthlyData.removeIf(date -> !functions.checkForCurrentMonth(date.getPurchaseDate()));` would work just as well, assuming it’s acceptable to modify the original List.

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code:

```java
monthlyData.stream()
   .filter(date -> functions.checkForCurrentMonth(date.getPurchaseDate()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Within this line the `collect` operation returns a `List`. You should store this `List` into your `monthlyData` reference to be returned later. So you should write like this:

```java
monthlyData = monthlyData.stream()
    .filter(date -> functions.checkForCurrentMonth(date.getPurchaseDate()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

your final function will be as follow:

```
public String getMonthlyExpensesNew() {
    Functions functions = new Functions();
    List<ShoppingMgnt> monthlyData = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        monthlyData = getRecordsAsList();
        //put the returned list in the same defined list
        monthlyData = monthlyData.stream()
        .filter(date -> functions.checkForCurrentMonth(date.getPurchaseDate()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }catch (SQLException sqlException){
        System.err.println("Error in getMonthlyExpensesNew");
    }
    //the return with updated list  
    return String.valueOf(monthlyData);
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained what you changed, and why.